# Avoiding multiple headers in pig output files

Tags: apache-pig

We use Pig to load files from directories containing thousands of files, transform them, and then output files that are a consolidation of the input.

We've noticed that the output files contain the header record of every file processed, i.e. the header appears multiple times in each file.

Is there any way to have the header only once per output file?

```
raw_data = LOAD '$INPUT' 
   USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',')
```

DO SOME TRANSFORMS

```
STORE data INTO '$OUTPUT' 
USING  org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage('|')
```

Comment: Do you specifically need CSVExcelStorage for output? If you use PigStorage it will not have any header (but can be put into separate file).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this option?

`SKIP_INPUT_HEADER`

See https://github.com/apache/pig/blob/31278ce56a18f821e9c98c800bef5e11e5396a69/contrib/piggybank/java/src/main/java/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/CSVExcelStorage.java#L85

Comment: I tried SKIP_INPUT_HEADER on LOAD with WRITE_OUTPUT_HEADER on STORE and we still get the header many times within each output files.